# bootstrap carousel not sliding on load

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a slider carousel with bootstrap. My 'active' image loads, but the controls and the slide don't work. As I am following a tutorial, I thought this would be an easy exercise for practice, but I've hit a snag. For anyone concerned about the boostrap.css link I posted the entire html doc ... but its functionality is working well otherwise, so I don't believe that is the issue here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="" content="Trey's Personal Website.">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Trey Coggins | Personal Website</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/index.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="styles/index-style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
   
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Trey Coggins</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bricks.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Let's build something together!</h2>
              </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/woods.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h2>Take a walk in the woods</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/stone.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h2>Elevate yourself to the next level</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>

      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

    </div>
  </header>



  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/trey-court-headshot.jpg" alt="Trey & Courtney">
        <h2>Trey & Courtney</h2>
        <p>She's the love of my life!</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">See more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/tootsie-smile.jpg" alt="Mama Tootsie">
        <h2>Bodhi & Tootsie</h2>
        <p>These two keep us young!</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">See more &raquo;</a></p>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/royal-hearts.jpg" alt="Royal Flush">
        <h2>Poker</h2>
        <p>Join the action!</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">See more &raquo;</a></p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your HTML page with all the code in it? I would like to see if you have correctly included the bootstrap's javascript/CSS file.

if you have not included Javascript. here are the javascript files that you need to include in your HTML code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap is running locally from my machine. It is linked appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item item active">
                <img class="col-lg-7 d-block w-100" src="img/bricks.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Let's build something together!</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/woods.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Take a walk in the woods</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/stone.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Elevate yourself to the next level</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <a href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" class="right carousel-control">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

    </div>
```